# Off-Topic flag options are incomplete

Tags: discussion, flags

I cannot flag questions as off topic if they do not relate to:

- Piracy
- Game development
- Speculations about games
- Game recommendations

I am pretty much in the dark on how to flag a question like "how many peaces of corn does a chicken eat per hour?". In all seriousness, there should be a default flag option that says something in the trend of "Question does not relate to Arqade".

Furthermore, if I would see a question that relates to another site within the SE network I would go and pick "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange Network". But there I only have the option to put it to meta.gaming. So that would not be an option either for the chicken question, or any other not related to Arqade question.

Comment: What's wrong with the "Other" off-topic reason?

Comment: @MatthewRead 3k and above sees an "other" close reason. There isn't an "other" flag.

Comment: Right, I forgot that the flag menu magically becomes the close menu when you choose that.  In that case I agree, there should be a general "Does not relate to gaming" flag reason like other sites have.  However, in the meantime you could use the "other" reason from the initial menu rather than the closing submenu.

Comment: @MatthewRead Sure, but that option call a moderator i believe. Which should not be necessary. The "other SE sites" needs work too, i seem only to be able to direct them here to meta.

Comment: [This meta question seems relevant](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7997/30115), although it seems we've since picked up an extra close reason.

Comment: @TrentHawkins we haven't, but [we're trying](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/8082/51318)